# How to separate discount in multi line in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to apply multiple discount in separate line.Right now i have coupn code and sales rule applied in same cart what should i do so cart and checkout page display relevant discount in separate line in magento2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Create `checkout_cart_index`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Ktpl\Extrafee\Block\Discounts" name="block.banner" as="block.custom.cms" template="Vendor_Module::discounts.phtml" before="-" />
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="before_grandtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                                    <!-- <item name="title" xsi:type="helper" translate="true" helper="Ktpl\Extrafee\Helper\Data::getTitle"/> -->
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2) Now create `fee.js` at**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals

```
define(
    [
        'Ktpl_Extrafee/js/view/checkout/summary/fee'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            },

            discounts: function() { 

                var alldiscount = window.discounts;

                return alldiscount;

            }

        });
    }
);
```

**3) Create `fee.html` at**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/fee.html

```
<!-- ko -->

<tr>
    <td>
        <table data-bind="foreach: discounts()">
            <tr class="totals fee excl" >
            <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
            <td class="amount">
                <span class="price" data-bind="text: amount"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>            
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- /ko -->
```

**4) Now create discounts and pass your array of discount**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/discounts.phtml

```
<?php

$totalDiscounts = $block->getAllDiscounts();

/* Your array should look like this
$discounts = [
                 ['title' => 'First Discount', 'amount' => '-10' ],
                 [ 'title' => 'Second Discount', 'amount' => '-5' ]
             ]; */
?>
<script>
    window.discounts = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($totalDiscounts) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: How we get the discount amount from quite based on rule id?